# Converting Jenkins working directory to remote directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I previously had a jenkins node running windows with a working directory outside of jenkins folder.
We now migrated the jenkins to Linux. All i want to ask is can i use the old windows working directory as a new remote directory for the linux  and connect it to the linux as slave node?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a mount point on linux to connect shared folder of old windows working directory ans use it as a new remote directory for the linux

Comment: Thanks,Instead of mounting on linux can we convert it to slave node via running jar command